# How can I remove crop marks in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, crop, microsoft-word-365

I have a document template in Microsoft Word and I would like to delete the empty space at the end of a large table cell. But a crop mark inhibits this.

I searched for how to remove a crop mark but all the pages I have found was about how not to display crop marks, which is not the same thing.

How can I remove that crop mark to delete that space after the crop mark in the cell?

Comment: Sounds like this could be either in the header or footer. If you doubleclick the header or footer area of the document, so you get into the editor, does that help? Alternatively it could be that a background image is set to the document that has the cropmarks

Comment: Why not simply delete the table cell with the large empty space?

Comment: This is probably not a crop mark. If you could upload the template online we could have a look at it.